# Rails3: Find records that have a relationship but exclude some by a specific value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Hi have two models (Rails3)

Aunt
Friends

Where

> aunt :has_many => friends

and

> friend :belongs_to => aunt

Now, I want to get all aunts that are not related to friend X

I tried something like:

> Aunt.includes(:friends).where('friends.id != ? ', X )

But it doesn't work.

PS: I also need to include the aunts that don't have any friends associated.

This is the output of :

```
@results = Aunt.custom(true).select('aunts.id, aunts.goal').joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN friends r ON aunts.id = r.aunt_id").where('r.other_value != ? or r.id is NULL', 4259 ).ordered_by_status_creation.select('aunts.id, aunts.goal')
```

> SELECT aunts.id, aunts.goal FROM `aunts` LEFT OUTER JOIN friends r ON
>   aunts.id = r.aunt_id WHERE `aunts`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND
>   `leads`.`type` IN ('MyType') AND (is_custom = 1) AND (r.another_value
>   != 4259 or r.id is NULL) ORDER BY status desc, aunts.id desc

Any ideas?

Comment: What does Aunt.joins(:childrens).where('childrens.id <> ? ', X ) give you?

Comment: That returns all the aunts @rainkinz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use scope as following

scope :without_house, lambda { |param| param ? {:conditions => ["related_id != ?", param.id]} : {} }

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
Aunt.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN friends ON aunts.id = friends.friend_id").where('friends.id != ? or friends.id is NULL', X ).select
```